# Infinite loop calling getSiteRefreshInfo

Tags: infinite-loop, yodlee

About 2 weeks ago I wrote a program implementing the [Add Site Account flow chart](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account).

I ran it a number of times over a span of several days, and it worked fine each time.

Then I worked on other things, and about a week later tried running the above program again.  Now it did not work, but got into a seemingly infinite loop on the call to getSiteRefreshInfo (the loop in the lower left corner of the flow chart.)  I tried running this a number of times over the next 3-4 days, and got into a loop each time. It looped for 20-30 minutes before I killed the program.  This is exactly the same source code that worked correctly a week earlier, using exactly the same credentials.

Each time "code" was 0, and "siteRefreshStatus" was "LOGIN_SUCCESS", which according to the flowchart meant I should wait 2-4 seconds and then repeat the call:

```
{
  "siteRefreshStatus": {
    "siteRefreshStatusId": 2,
    "siteRefreshStatus": "LOGIN_SUCCESS"
  },
  "siteRefreshMode": {
    "refreshModeId": 2,
    "refreshMode": "NORMAL"
  },
  "updateInitTime": 1418945894,
  "nextUpdate": 1418946794,
  "code": 0,
  "itemRefreshInfo": [
    {
      "memItemId": 10070147,
      "itemSuggestedFlow": {
        "suggestedFlowId": 2,
        "suggestedFlow": "REFRESH"
      },
      "errorCode": 405,
      "retryCount": 0
    }
  ],
  "noOfRetry": 0
}
```

The account I'm passing to addSiteAccount1 is an American Express credit card account, and this is the only account I've added for this user (in other words, this is the only account that needs to be refreshed).  Once while the program was in a loop, I manually logged onto the American Express website using these same credentials, and I could view the account, get the list of recent transactions, etc.  I realize that Yodlee probably uses a different interface than the browser does, but this did show me that the Amex website was up and functional.

I tried letting the loop run for more than 30 minutes to see what happened.  After an hour and 55 minutes I got this exception:

```
{
  "errorOccurred": "true",
  "exceptionType": "Unknown Exception Occurred",
  "referenceCode": "_022c5fa3-3933-4491-b390-1150d8b28ab3",
  "detailedMessage": "Technical Difficulty Processing Request"
}
```

I tried running the program various times over the next 3-4 days and it got into a loop each time.  Then it abruptly started running correctly again, and at the moment is still running correctly.  Note that the exact same source code and credentials ran correctly for a while, then got into a loop for 3-4 days, and is now running correctly again.

I have two questions about this:

1) How should I exit from such a loop?  The way I interpret the API Flowchart is that I should loop until I get a value for "code" or "siteRefreshStatus" that tells me to exit the loop.  I could easily implement my own timer, but I don't know what time value would be appropriate in all cases.  Yodlee is in a better position to know if the loop has gone on for too long, so I would expect a return like REFRESH_TIMED_OUT in this case.

2) If we had been running this code in production, we would not have been able to refresh this customer's information for at least 3 days, which for our application would be an extremely long time.  Is there anything else we can try in this case?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're suffering from a different issue: your itemRefreshInfo has error code 405, which [this page](https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes) says is: "Update Request Canceled(405):Your account was not updated because you canceled the request."

I believe you're cancelling your request somehow.